# Reactjs don't duplicate my message after update state

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, reactjs

I was following the example this blog and the question arose me after implementing

https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat

Summarizing, before send a message via websocket the state of messages is updated.
And when server receives that message, they send a broadcast to all clients, indluding myself. 
Thereat, client updates the state with this same message

Why this message does not appear 2 times?
I don't want that message appear 2 times, but I want to know why it happens

Client code:

```
socket.on('send:message', this.messageRecieve);
...
handleMessageSubmit : function(message){
    Messages.push(message);
    this.setState({ messages : Messages });
    socket.emit('send:message', message);
},

messageRecieve: function(message){
    Messages.push(message);
    this.setState({ messages : Messages });
},
```

Server code:

```
socket.on('send:message', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('send:message', {
        user: name,
        text: data.text
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't receive me own message?

Comment: We don't know if you receive this message, look in your logs and tell us. We can't know if this is a React render problem or a Websocket/server problem...

Comment: I asked this because I suspected that this would be a behavior of socket.io...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server does not send the message to the connected user.

As per the socket.io documentation, this API sends to all but the owner of the socket:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('send:message')
```

https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat/blob/master/routes/socket.js

Comment: I didn't found at socket.io docs it, however it is how it works, that explains my doubts, thank you